# React Native - Scroll Listview at particular position - Programatically

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-scrollview

In iOS with Objective-C we can make `UITableView` scroll to the particular row index by using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method but in React-Native I did NOT find such a way to scroll `Listview` at particular row index.

Following is the scenario,

1. There is `Listview` with such expandable rows like while tapping it expands and the expandable row contains `TextInput` component.
2. While inputting text in `TextInput`, the keyboard will be shown up and ideally at that moment `Listview` should be scrolled to up (once the keyboard get down `Listview` should be scrolled down to its previous position).

This can be easily achieved with Native-iOS but I am stuck in React-Native.

[image]

---

**I TRIED FOLLOWING WAY BUT DID NOT ACHIEVE WELL**

There is a method called `scrollTo(x:0,y:10,animated:true)` in `Listview` component (actually its method of `Scrollview`) by which it can be scrolled up/down based on the **y coordinate** of the parent view.

I successfully receive Keyboard's Up & Down events in my code and based on that I can somehow manage with `scrollTo` method (by calculating the **y coordinate**) when Keyboard gets up (as mentioned in @Alexey's answer) but I have NO idea about how to calculate **y coordinate** when Keyboard gets down? (At this moment ideally, the Listview should scroll down to its previous position).

Any help or hint would be appreciated!

Comment: I had the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750424/react-native-listview-how-to-scroll-to-a-particular-row

Answer (score 5):

What about `row height * item index`? Let's say you want to scroll to 20th element in your ListView. Each row has `height: 50`. We calculate an offset at 20th element by using formula I mentioned above: `50 * 20 = 1000`. Then use `scrollTo(0, 1000)` and you'll scroll to the desired element.

To be able to scroll back, you need to store an offset before you apply a `scrollTo` function:

```
var scrollProperties = this.refs.listView.scrollProperties;
var scrollOffset = scrollProperties.contentLength - scrollProperties.visibleLength;
```

After you hook up on keyboard's event (`keyboardWillHide` from the `DeviceEventEmitter`), you can do `scrollTo` to the previous offset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I already had this trick in my mind. But here it's getting trouble when the Keyboard gets down. At this moment ideally, the Listview should scroll down to its previous position but how can I come to know its previous position? I hope you getting my query..! Please  check point-2 in my question ````(once the keyboard get down Listview should be scrolled down to its previous position)````

Comment: Well, in this case you store your previous offset